# changing the colour of an echo command

Tags: php, echo

ive searched this question on google and i've found many answers but none of them seem to work in my situation.

i need to echo out a command in orange, but everything i do doesn't seem to work.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row ['title_name'];
  echo "<br />";
  echo $row['date'];
  echo "<br />";
  echo $row['message'];
  echo "<br />";
  }
```

i need the title_name to be in orange `"#FF9900"`

has any got got any ideas on how i can do this

many thanks Connor

Comment: Do you happen to know a thing called HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<span style='color:orange'>".$row ['title_name']."</span>";
  echo "<br />";
  echo $row['date'];
  echo "<br />";
  echo $row['message'];
  echo "<br />";
  }
```

that all

Answer (score 1):

```
...
echo "<span style=\"color: #FF9900;\">".$row['title_name']."</span>";
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<span style="color: #FF9900">' . $row ['title_name'] . '</span>';
```

?

Answer (score 1):

There's this thing called HTML... and another thing called CSS...

```
echo '<span style="color: #ff9900">', $row['title_name'], '</span>';
echo '<font color="#ff9900">', $row['title_name'], '</font>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use some HTML.

```
echo '<span style="color: #ff9900;">'.$row['title_name'].'</span>';
```

Actually you should put the CSS seperately, but this works as an example :X

Answer (score 1):

`echo "<font style='color:#FF9900'>".$row ['title_name']."</font>";` should work as it looks like you are developing a web app.